# How to remove dots in UITextfield?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

In iOS, I am using one text field the length of the text field id too long so it is showing dots at the end of the text field. I need to remove the dots. I have used `lineBreakMode` also.

See the code I'm using.

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(titleListTxtFld.frame.size.width, 1000); //here 1000 for maximum height u can increase this if u want
CGSize strSize = [titleListTxtFld.text sizeWithFont:titleListTxtFld.font constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];
CGRect newframe = CGRectMake(0, 0, strSize.width, strSize.height);
[titleListTxtFld.text drawInRect:newframe 
                  withFont:titleListTxtFld.font 
             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip 
                 alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
```

Please anyone help me on this.

Comment: Do you want to change the size of your textfield depending on the text or just remove the dots or just change the font of the text to fit it in?

Comment: i just want to remove the dots. thats enough

Comment: use UITextView for your requirement

Comment: You should never call drawRect directly as you show - this is clearly documented in the class reference. I agree with @Prince use a UITextView instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is (Remove dot and clip text to frame)-

your can remove dot from UITextField calling following code

```
[self.yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

you can also hide default keyboard [if you use any custom keyboard] using following code

```
// Hide keyboard for Dial Pad, but show blinking cursor 
UIView *dummyKeyboardView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
yourTextField.inputView = dummyKeyboardView; 
[dummyKeyboardView release];
```

But I think IlNero's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16913474/667115) is better for you if you want to show all text (does not clip).